# Assign each instance of an object a number from a static int to give a unique name C#

Tags: c#, variables, static, instance, counter

I have a class Foo in C# that has a string name and I want each one to have a unique name. What I wanted to do is get the name from creating a static int variable and then assigning it to a local instance int variable to which I add to the end of the string. This does not work though, how would I be able to get my desired result.

```
class Foo
{
    static int count = 0;
    int fooNum;
    string name;

    public Foo
    {
        ++count;
        fooNum = count;
        name = "Foo" + fooNum;
        Console.WriteLine(name);
    }
}

int main()
{
   for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   {
      Foo test = new Foo();
   }
}
```

Actual Output:
Foo5
Foo5
Foo5
Foo5
Foo5

Desired Output:
Foo0
Foo1
Foo2
Foo3
Foo4

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: you've posted code that doesn't compile...

Comment: @MitchWheat. _"This does not work though"_...

Comment: "does not work" does not mean "it does not compile" in my book....By definition it can't work unless it compiles... But it can 'not work' when it compiles also...

Comment: ...especially when "actual output" is attributed to the code. If it doesn't compile, then there's no output.

Comment: since you have an answer, can I suggest you accept one (when you are able to) and maybe even cast upvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't compile. Correcting it to:

```
class Foo
{
    static int count = 0;
    int fooNum;
    string name;

    public Foo()
    {
        ++count;
        fooNum = count;
        name = "Foo" + fooNum;
        Console.WriteLine(name);
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Foo test = new Foo();
    }
}
```

makes it compile and work like a charm. It prints

```
Foo1
Foo2
Foo3
Foo4
Foo5
```

Comment: So I found out why it wasn't incrementing. In my code I have a currentObject holder that only calls the constructor once and then whenever it adds something to a List it just does a shallow copy not calling the constructor. The reason it goes to 1025 (in my code not the example) is because I call the constructor to first init the list. To rectify all of this I have created a function that increments the static variable. Thank you all, I would've kept thinking it wasn't working if you guys didn't show me that I was right. Thanks again all!

Answer (score 1):

Mitch and Tudor have correct examples, but I would still point out **why** your code doesn't work:

Your code doesn't work because you are missing parentheses on your `Foo` constructor, which causes the code to not compile. If you are ignoring this compiler error you are probably running a previous build which produces the output you are seeing. Fix the constructor and you'll see that your code will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This code works as expected:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication68
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
           { 
              Foo test = new Foo();
              Console.WriteLine(test.name); 
           } 
        }
    }

    class Foo 
    { 
        private static int count = 0; 
        public string name; 

        public Foo() 
        { 
            int fooNum = ++count; 
            name = "Foo" + fooNum; 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Please note that I've moved the `Console.WriteLine()` to a more correct place in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try collecting your Foos into a generic Collection, such as:

```
List<Foo> myFooList;
```

Then as you add in more Foos to your List, you can use the index number to identify it.